# При редактировании DOM дерева, документ прокручивается, как это остановить

Tags: javascript

Вот пример кода для наглядности, при перемещении одного блока фокусировка начинает следовать за ним и смещает скролл. Как это предотвратить за исключением ручного сдвига скролла на ту же высоту

```js
const doc = document.getElementById("qwe")

setInterval(()=>{
    doc.appendChild(doc.firstChild)
},1000)
```

```css
#qwe {
  height: 3000px;
}
.block {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="qwe">
  <p class="block"></p>
  <p class="block"></p>
  <p class="block"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас setInterval бесконечно раз в секунду добавляет, первого ребенка блока qwe(в него же), и поэтому прокручивается экран.
Чтобы это остановить надо определить id вашего setInterval при создании и остановить его с помощью функции clearInterval(id).
Пример:

```
const timerId = setInterval(() => doc.appendChild(doc.firstChild, 1000);
```

// делаем setTimeout чтобы остановить работу нашего setInterval() через 5 секунд

```
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(timerId), 5000);
```

Comment: Это решение ни как не помогает, ибо такое же происходит если перерендеривать список в React просто вставляя первый элемент их массива в конец